# How to use WebDriverEvent Listener in Page Factory Pattern

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I got the code how to use WebDriverEventListener in normal way in selenium.
But don't know how to use the same for PageFactory pattern.

The Code is as follows, first need to implement WebDriverEventListner interface

```
public class EventHandler implements WebDriverEventListener{

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("inside method afterChangeValueOf on " + arg0.toString());
        log.info("inside method afterChangeValueOf on " + arg0.toString());
    }

    public void afterClickOn(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("inside method afterClickOn on " + arg0.toString());
    }

    public void afterFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("Find happened on " + arg1.toString() 
                + " Using method " + arg0.toString());
    }

    public void afterNavigateBack(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        log.info("Inside the after navigateback to " + arg0.getCurrentUrl());
    }

    public void afterNavigateForward(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("Inside the afterNavigateForward to " + arg0.getCurrentUrl());
    }

    public void afterNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("Inside the afterNavigateTo to " + arg0);
    }

    public void afterScript(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("Inside the afterScript to, Script is " + arg0);
    }

    public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        log.info("Inside the beforeChangeValueOf method");
    }

    public void beforeClickOn(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("About to click on the " + arg0.toString());

    }

    public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("Just before finding element " + arg1.toString());

    }

    public void beforeNavigateBack(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("Just before beforeNavigateBack " + arg0.getCurrentUrl());

    }

    public void beforeNavigateForward(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("Just before beforeNavigateForward " + arg0.getCurrentUrl());

    }

    public void beforeNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("Just before beforeNavigateTo " + arg0);
    }

    public void beforeScript(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("Just before beforeScript " + arg0);
    }

    public void onException(Throwable arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        log.info("Exception occured at " + arg0.getMessage());

    }

    public void afterNavigateRefresh(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void beforeNavigateRefresh(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Next we need to use this in script as below:

```
@BeforeClass()
    public void signIn() throws Exception
        {

        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(PROPERTIES_FILEPATH);

        log = Logger.getLogger("SuperTest");

        //Delete the test-output directory
        try
        {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("./test-output"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        //Get the Browser Type and initiate the Driver
        driver = GenericUtilLibrary.initializeBrowser(driver, BROWSER_TYPE);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //create a object for EventFiringWebDriver Class
        eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);

        //create object of the class (EventHandler) which implemented WebDriverEventListener Interface. 
        handler = new EventHandler();

       //register handler object with EventFiringWebDriver
        eventDriver.register(handler);


        eventDriver.get(URL);


        //CLICK ON SIGNIN BUTTON IN LOGIN PAGE.
        LoginPage lpage = new LoginPage(driver);
        lpage.clickSignInButton();


        //ENTER USER CREDENTIALS AND CLICK ON SIGNON BUTTON IN SIGNIN PAGE.
        SignInPage spage = new SignInPage(driver);
        spage.clickSignInButton(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    }
```

Once registered, eventDriver will handle the logging the actions of WebDriver, when we use eventDriver for all the WebElements.

Till eventDriver.get(URL); i have no problem but when it comes to next step, i am calling Object Page Classes and invoking their methods. To Send eventDriver instead of driver object, i am getting NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION when it called the first method itself.

I have no clue how to use WebDriverEventListener.

Please any one help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have a simple error.

**Instead of:**

```
 //CLICK ON SIGNIN BUTTON IN LOGIN PAGE.
        LoginPage lpage = new LoginPage(driver);
        lpage.clickSignInButton();
```

**You should use:**

```
 //CLICK ON SIGNIN BUTTON IN LOGIN PAGE.
        LoginPage lpage = new LoginPage(handler);
        lpage.clickSignInButton();
```

Comment: Thanks Denis for your reply. When tried as above i am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException;`    it is coming  at `com.tecnotree.CLM.Commons.EventHandler.beforeFindBy(EventHandler.java:67)` because the LoginPage constrcutor is as below :         `public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {           
        this.driver = driver;   
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);   
    }`

Comment: Try to use "handler " instead of "eventDriver"

Comment: @SaradaAkurathi, Try to check this example, it may help you https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-event-listener-example

Comment: Hi Dev, Thanks for your help. In that example also, in @Test methods , they are directly finding element by eDrvier.findElement() method, not initializing by pageFactory design.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in WebDriverEventListener class, not in initializing the constructor for each class. With @Denis suggestion it will work. In WebDriverEventListener Class , wrong is with  beforeFindBy

```
public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    log.info("Just before finding element " + arg1.toString());

}
```

it should be as

```
public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    log.info("Just before finding element " + arg0);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue to configure WebDriverEventListener with my project. I did figured out by passing object of EventFiringWebDriver instead of driver.
And, Voila, it worked awesome!

```
    public static EventFiringWebDriver eventFiringWebDriver;
    public static WebDriverEventListener webDriverEventListener;
    eventFiringWebDriver= new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
    webDriverEventListener= new WebEventListener();
    eventFiringWebDriver.register(webDriverEventListener);

    LoginPage lpage = new LoginPage(eventFiringWebDriver);
```